# I'm getting this error : 'AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Adam''

Tags: tensorflow, keras, optimizer-hints

I'm trying to run this code in Google Colab :

from keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

for i in range(5):

```
print(i)
model_mix = Model(inputs=[visible, visible1], outputs=x)
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=6, verbose=2, mode='auto') 
model_mix.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=adam)
model_mix.fit(
    [x_text_train, x_img_train], y_text_train, callbacks=[checkpointer_cnn,monitor],**strong text**
    validation_data=([x_text_test, x_img_test], y_text_test),
    epochs=1000)
```

It worked fine before but now it is giving me an error. Can someone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove optimizers., i.e. `adam = Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)`
It should work like this.

Comment: It worked but i'm not getting good accuracy when I train my model. 
What parameters should I change to improve the accuracy of my model?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without seeing your code, especially the model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of diffenert editions of keras, on keras2.8.0 try:

```
 adam = optimizers.adam_v2.Adam(lr=0.01, ......)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

**Instead of**

```
from keras import optimizers from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```